# When to load and set the min/maxTrackImages so that they appear in the IB

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uislider

I have the below code in a subclass of UISlider. I would like to load the images and have them appear in the interface builder.

```
- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder
{
    [self sharedInit];
}

- (void)sharedInit
{
    UIImage *minImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"MinSliderImage"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 1, 0, 0)];
    UIImage *maxImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"MaxSliderImage"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 1)];
    UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SliderThumb"];

    [self setMinimumTrackImage:minImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

It looks correct when the application is run but the images are not displayed on the IB.

[image]

The desired effect can be achieved by creating IBInspectable Image properties and loading the same images. Leading it me to believe I am loading the immages at the wrong time.

```
- (void)setMinimumTrackImage:(UIImage *)minImage
{
    UIImage *img = [minImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 1, 0, 0)];
    [self setMinimumTrackImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)setMaximumTrackImage:(UIImage *)maxImage
{
    UIImage *img = [maxImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 1)];
    [self setMaximumTrackImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)setCurrentThumbImage:(UIImage *)thumbImage
{
    [self setThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

[image]

So my question is. How can I hard code the images, set the min/maxTrackImages, and still have them show up on the IB?

Comment: Is there a reason you're setting these images in `prepareForInterfaceBuilder`? Doing that means they'll only apply in Interface Builder, and not when your app is actually running...

Comment: The function sharedInit is also called in initWithFrame and initWithCoder. As mentioned but I cut it out because I didn't think it was relevant. As mentioned using the top method the slider renders properly in the simulator but not in the interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting `IB_DESIGNABLE` before your class declaration in your .h file. That will tell the Interface Builder to render your UISlider in the storyboard the way it's going to appear when you run the app.

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface YourCostumeSlider : UISlider
```

Comment: I already have the IB_DESIGNABLE attribute. The issue is images are loading in as nil in the sharedInit even if I load it using the main bundle.